# Forcing: a notion of revised game

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, game-theory, forcing

Suppose we have a game played by players I and II to build generic extensions.

Can someone guess what **revised** means in the revised game in the Claim $3.2(2)$ ?

The game is given in the first snippet and revised game in the second.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1982) Pseudo-completeness. In: Proper Forcing. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 940. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg

Comment: @DanielS. The material in your reference looks the same as in Proper and Improper forcing by Shelah. But I still do not know how the revised game looks like as opposed to "ordinary/original" game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim $(3)$ says:

> If [stuff] then in the definition of the game, it does not matter if we demand [thing].

That is, (under the assumption [stuff]) there are two versions of the game, one of which does and one of which does not demand [thing]; which is the original and which is the revised just depends on the original phrasing.

In this case the original version of the game is the one without this special demand and the revised game has it added.